# How to stop MPSolver of Google OR-Tools at the first feasible solution found?

Tags: or-tools, mixed-integer-programming

I have a MIP (BP, maximization) that takes too long to compute and I'd like to have MPSolver return the first feasible solution it finds, also, I'd like to know if I use RELATIVE_MIP_GAP solver parameter correctly.
I have tried two things:

#### Callback

I have searched the docs and have not found a callback possibility for MPSolver's solution iteration process (only for CpSolver) with which one could implement stopping on the first feasible solution found.

#### Relative gap as termination criterion

I tried using RELATIVE_MIP_GAP like so (this is Kotlin language):

```
val mpSolverParameters = MPSolverParameters().apply {
    setDoubleParam(MPSolverParameters.DoubleParam.RELATIVE_MIP_GAP, 1.0)
}
solver.solve(mpSolverParameters)
```

I've seen as a documentation comment somewhere that a 0.05 value for RELATIVE_MIP_GAP means a 5% gap, so 1.0 should denote a 100% gap.
But it did not work. I know it because when I have set a time limit, it returned a solution at the end of the time limit, but when I ran the same problem without a time limit, it just went on and did not return anything even after much more time than when it stopped at the time limit previously.
If I understand relative gaps correctly, if I set a value of 1.0 for this relative gap parameter, the solver should stop at any feasible solution found immediately, because the objective value of any integer solution is inside a 100% relative difference of the objective value for any continuous state of the variables. I should add that my objective function is always positive, so there's no problem of these two having different signs.

### Solution remarks

- Both of [Laurent Perron's suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73038452/10399733) work for my case.
- If using SCIP as the solver, we may call  `solver.setSolverSpecificParametersAsString("limits/solutions = 1")` to get the first feasible solution, but that will be a poor quality one. We may increase this value passed as we see fit.
  Check out time limit too: call `setTimeLimit(timeInMs)` on your solver object. It will return the best feasible solution found so far, or the unsolved state if no solution has been found at all.
- Still not sure why RELATIVE_MIP_GAP didn't work, it is part of the API, not a solver specific parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try CP-SAT ? Does it fit there ? meaning no continuous variables.

Can you remove the objective function ?